# How to calculate difference between timestamps given some conditions?

Tags: r

I would like to determine the difference between timestamps regading a userID. Here I just want to measure the difference between those users who have a login und logout status. There are some users haven only logout our login status. For them I just would like to mark dem as `NA`:

Some data:

```
  library(dplyr)
  start <- as.POSIXct("2012-01-15")
  interval <- 70
  end <- start + as.difftime(1, units="days")
  tseq<- seq(from=start, by=interval*70, to=end)
  employeID <-c("1_e","1_e","2_b","2_b","3_c","3_c","100_c","4_d","4_d","52_f","9_f","9_f","7_u","7_u","10_5","22_2","33_a","33_a")
  status<- c("login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","logout","login","logout","login")
  # put together
  data <- data.frame(tseq, employeID, status)

           tseq            employeID   status
  #1  2012-01-15 00:00:00       1_e  login
  #2  2012-01-15 01:21:40       1_e logout
  #3  2012-01-15 02:43:20       2_b  login
  #4  2012-01-15 04:05:00       2_b logout
  #5  2012-01-15 05:26:40       3_c  login
  #6  2012-01-15 06:48:20       3_c logout
  #7  2012-01-15 08:10:00     100_c  login
  #8  2012-01-15 09:31:40       4_d logout
  #9  2012-01-15 10:53:20       4_d  login
  #10 2012-01-15 12:15:00      52_f logout
  #11 2012-01-15 13:36:40       9_f  login
  #12 2012-01-15 14:58:20       9_f logout
  #13 2012-01-15 16:20:00       7_u  login
  #14 2012-01-15 17:41:40       7_u logout
  #15 2012-01-15 19:03:20      10_5 logout
  #16 2012-01-15 20:25:00      22_2  login
  #17 2012-01-15 21:46:40      33_a logout
  #18 2012-01-15 23:08:20      33_a  login  


  test<- data %>% 
    group_by(employeID) %>% 
    mutate(time.difference = tseq - lag(tseq))
```

However, that seems only to produce a time.difference constant

Comment: It is because you've created a constant in your example. Each timestamp have an interval of `interval*70` as you defined in `seq`. So  `70*70 = 1.3611 hours`.
There is no problem.

Comment: Please don't let your question stagnate. You've got a few answers, and more comments, but you haven't responded to any of them. At a minimum, come back and let us know what worked or didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this. Mainly, it looks like you're using `mutate` when you want `summarise`. Also, I've converted the `status` column from factor to character, and included an `ifelse` statement to only take the users with both "login" and "logout" entries:

```
test <- data %>% 
    mutate( status = as.character( status ) ) %>%
    group_by( employeID ) %>% 
    summarise( time.difference = ifelse( "login" %in% status && "logout" %in% status, 
                                         difftime( tseq[ status == "logout" ], tseq[ status == "login" ] ), 
                                         NA ) 
    )
```

Which gives:

```
> head( test )
# A tibble: 6 × 2
employeID time.difference
      <fctr>           <dbl>
1       1_e        1.361111
2      10_5              NA
3     100_c              NA
4       2_b        1.361111
5      22_2              NA
6       3_c        1.361111
```

As others have suggested, your data does contain constant intervals of time, so wherever there is a relevant value, it's always the same. I assume your actual data looks a little different, so you'll get more sensical output.

Comment: I modified your example to include only those `employeID`'s which have both "login" and "logout": `data %>% group_by(employeID) %>% dplyr::filter("login" %in% status & "logout" %in% status) %>% group_by(employeID) %>% dplyr::summarise(interval = difftime(tseq[status == "logout"], tseq[status == "login"]))`

Comment: The OP wanted to keep them, marked as NA: "There are some users haven only logout our login status. For them I just would like to mark dem as NA:". That's why I wrote the `ifelse` that way.

Answer (score 1):

We first filter groups which have unpaired status by checking count for each group. With `dplyr::do` we then
calculate time difference for each group

```
 library(dplyr)
  start <- as.POSIXct("2012-01-15")
  interval <- 70
  end <- start + as.difftime(1, units="days")
  tseq<- seq(from=start, by=interval*70, to=end)
  employeID <-c("1_e","1_e","2_b","2_b","3_c","3_c","100_c","4_d","4_d","52_f","9_f","9_f","7_u","7_u","10_5","22_2","33_a","33_a")
  status<- c("login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","login","logout","logout","login","logout","login")
  # put together
  DF <- data.frame(tseq, employeID, status)

           tseq            employeID   status
  #1  2012-01-15 00:00:00       1_e  login
  #2  2012-01-15 01:21:40       1_e logout
  #3  2012-01-15 02:43:20       2_b  login
  #4  2012-01-15 04:05:00       2_b logout
  #5  2012-01-15 05:26:40       3_c  login
  #6  2012-01-15 06:48:20       3_c logout
  #7  2012-01-15 08:10:00     100_c  login
  #8  2012-01-15 09:31:40       4_d logout
  #9  2012-01-15 10:53:20       4_d  login
  #10 2012-01-15 12:15:00      52_f logout
  #11 2012-01-15 13:36:40       9_f  login
  #12 2012-01-15 14:58:20       9_f logout
  #13 2012-01-15 16:20:00       7_u  login
  #14 2012-01-15 17:41:40       7_u logout
  #15 2012-01-15 19:03:20      10_5 logout
  #16 2012-01-15 20:25:00      22_2  login
  #17 2012-01-15 21:46:40      33_a logout
  #18 2012-01-15 23:08:20      33_a  login  


  testDF<- DF %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(employeID) %>%
    dplyr::filter(count(unique(status)) > 1 ) %>% 
    dplyr::do(.,data.frame(logINTime =.$tseq[.$status=="login"],logOUTTime =.$tseq[.$status=="logout"],
    deltaTime=difftime(.$tseq[.$status=="logout"],.$tseq[.$status=="login"],units="secs"))) %>%
    as.data.frame()


testDF
  # employeID           logINTime          logOUTTime deltaTime
# 1       1_e 2012-01-15 00:00:00 2012-01-15 01:21:40      4900
# 2       2_b 2012-01-15 02:43:20 2012-01-15 04:05:00      4900
# 3       3_c 2012-01-15 05:26:40 2012-01-15 06:48:20      4900
# 4      33_a 2012-01-15 23:08:20 2012-01-15 21:46:40     -4900
# 5       4_d 2012-01-15 10:53:20 2012-01-15 09:31:40     -4900
# 6       7_u 2012-01-15 16:20:00 2012-01-15 17:41:40      4900
# 7       9_f 2012-01-15 13:36:40 2012-01-15 14:58:20      4900
```

Comment: this gives the same result as OP's approach, except considerably longer.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to create a constant time interval:

```
tseq<- seq(from=start, by=interval*70, to=end)
```

So when you take the difference again, wouldn't it be constant?

Comment: I agree, but may I suggest making this a comment, rather than an answer?